# How to change textbox value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change a textbox value.
am trying following javascript but in both the alerts am getting image only. ie. 
`$('#FileName').val = "testimage.jpg";` is not changing the text box field value.

```
<x:input type="textbox" id="FileName"
width="210px" value=""/>

if ($("#FileName").val() == "image") {
    alert($("#FileName").val())
    $('#FileName').val = "testimage.jpg";
    alert($("#FileName").val())
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

val is a method, not a property, so:

```
$('#FileName').val("testimage.jpg";)
```

Comment: The question is about using javascript not jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

you have used jquery

try  `$('#FileName').val("testimage.jpg");`

and using javascript  `document.getElementById('')`

```
document.getElementById('FileName').value = "testimage.jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
if ($("#FileName").val() == "image") {
    alert($("#FileName").val())
    $('#FileName').val("testimage.jpg");
    alert($("#FileName").val())
}
```